# M2 Filter shows different number while after applying the filter it returns more

Tags: magento2, php, filter

When navigating to a `category`, the `filter` shows a number which is different from what the `result` returns when clicking on it.

This is what I could see:

[image]

This is the result after applying the filter temperature sensor:

[image]

As you can see, it shows 1 in the filter but returns `13 products`. the 13 products are okay, that's what I need as you can see in here:

[image]

I found the template, but its hard to see where this happens. Does anybody have an idea where to look first?

Comment: try to run reindex

Comment: @Max Doens't work , already tried that